# 'Incorrect number of dimensions' when running Zelig 'arima' on imputed data

Tags: r, time-series, r-zelig

I'm getting an error when I try to run an `arima` model with the `zelig` package. I'm using MI data with 20 imputations that were created with Amelia. Here is a short summary of my id and response variables:

```
 $ imp20:'data.frame':  442 obs. of  50 variables:
  ..$ region                     : Factor w/ 4 levels "Central Africa",..: 3     3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ subregionid                : Factor w/ 4 levels "FC","FE","FS",..: 3 3     3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ country                    : Factor w/ 34 levels "Angola","Benin",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ ISO2                       : Factor w/ 34 levels "AO","BF","BJ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ ISO3                       : Factor w/ 34 levels "AGO","BEN","BFA",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ year                       : num [1:442] 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 ...
  ..$ cap.lat                    : num [1:442] -8.5 -8.5 -8.5 -8.5 -8.5 -8.5 -8.5 -8.5 -8.5 -8.5 ...
  ..$ cap.long                   : num [1:442] 13.2 13.2 13.2 13.2 13.2 ...
  ..$ NGDP_RPCH                  : num [1:442] 14.53 5.25 10.88 18.26 20.73 ...
  ..$ NGDPD                      : num [1:442] 3.18 3.31 3.38 3.44 3.48 ...
  ..$ NGDPDPC                    : num [1:442] 2.68 2.69 2.72 2.75 2.78 ...
  ..$ NGSD_NGDP                  : num [1:442] 10.62 7.77 12.63 26.98 40.94     
...
 ..$ PIKE.regional              : num [1:442] 0.225 0.295 0.287 0.358 0.357 ...
  ..$ Definite.Probable          : num [1:442] 36 36 36 36 36.1 ...
  ..$ Elephant.range             : num [1:442] 406006 433613 511662 456046 459418 ...
  ..$ Change.by.year             : num [1:442] 0.000463 0.000463 0.000463 0.000463 0.000463 ...
  ..$ Diff.from.expected         : num [1:442] -0.0415 -0.0415 -0.0415 -0.0415 -0.0415 ...
```

`Diff.from.expected` is my response variable. And here is the code that I've run along with the error I'm getting.

```
z1 <- zarima$new()
> z1$zelig(Diff.from.expected~GNI, order=c(1,0,1), model="arima",

+                data = a.coVarsTrans.more, ts="year", cs="country")

Error in data[, cs] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

So it appears to me that there is an issue with the `cs='country'` call, but I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm planning to add more independent variables, but want to make sure that a basic model works first, which clearly it doesn't.

Here is the link to my [saved Amelia .Rdata file](https://github.com/ldlathrop/Elephant-data-analysis/blob/master/coVarsTrans.RData).

Comment: I'm not a `Zelig` user, but looking at the source, `zelig` expects the `data` argument to be a dataframe, but you're passing `a.coVarsTrans.more`, which is the output from your MI procedure. That's why you're getting the "incorrect number of dimensions" error.

Comment: Actually, I'm using `Zelig` *because* it can supposedly be used with `Amelia` MI output. The documentation doesn't specify a different call for such data, which is why this is so baffling.

Comment: Right -- so e.g. `zelig(Diff.from.expected ~ GNI, model = "arima", data = a.coVarsTrans.more)` works -- but it doesn't take `ts` and `cs` arguments, which presumably you want.